# Getting this TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly when I am not trying to convert the int value

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion, python-3.5

I have looked through a lot of the questions on this error but they don't seem to be able to help me understand my problem with this error I am getting.  In the following code I'm simply trying to add 1 to a variable.  The variable is never part of an input from the user, which is why I am having troubles with it.

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:/Python Programs/troll game 2.py", line 966, in <module>
    main()
  File "I:/Python Programs/troll game 2.py", line 35, in main
    trolls, playersGold = getmainFight(playersHP, playersMP, trollsHP, mobLevel, trolls, playersGold, dmgBonus, classDMGbonus, weaponBreak, trollBonus, healthPot, manaPot, playerClass, pMaxHP, pMaxMP, playerLevel)
  File "I:/Python Programs/troll game 2.py", line 220, in getmainFight
    playersHP, playersGold, playersMP, dmgBonus, healthPot, manaPot, playerXP, trolls = gettrollDeath(classDMGbonus, playerXP, mobLevel, trolls, playersHP, playersGold, playersMP, playerClass, healthPot, manaPot, dmgBonus, pMaxHP, pMaxMP, playerLevel)
  File "I:/Python Programs/troll game 2.py", line 347, in gettrollDeath
    healthPot, dmgBonus, playersHP, playersGold, manaPot, pMaxHP = getplayerRewards(healthPot, dmgBonus, playersHP, playersGold, playerClass, manaPot, pMaxMP)
  File "I:/Python Programs/troll game 2.py", line 378, in getplayerRewards
    healthPot += 1
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

I'm going to put the module that this is part of so you can see, but like I said, at no point is the healthPot variable part of an input from the user and I do not know why it is thinking I want to change the variable's int value to a str value:

```
def getplayerRewards(healthPot, dmgBonus, playersHP, playersGold, playerClass, manaPot, pMaxHP):
    loot = random.randint(1, 100)
    if loot >= 96:
            pMaxHP += 5
            playersHP = pMaxHP
            print("A cleric passes by and buffs you for 5HP's, you now have", playersHP, "HP's!")                

    elif loot >= 76 and loot <= 95:
            dmgBonus += 2
            if playerClass == "Warrior":
                    print("You search around and find a Wet Stone to sharpet your Sword!")

            if playerClass == "Cleric":
                    print("You search around and find a Magic Wand!")

            if playerClass == "Mage":
                    print("You search around and find a Magic Wand!")

            if playerClass == "Scout":
                    print("You search around and find some Poison for your weapon!")

    elif loot >= 46 and loot <= 75:
            healthPot += 1
            print("You search around and find a Health Potion.")

    elif loot >= 16 and loot <= 45:
            manaPot += 1
            print("You search around and find a Mana Potion.")

    else:
            goldReward = random.randint(3, 10)
            playersGold += goldReward
            print("You search around and find", goldReward, "gold pieces!")

    return healthPot, dmgBonus, playersHP, playersGold, manaPot, pMaxHP
```

The healthPot variable is first set when the user picks his characters class such as:

```
if playerClass == "Scout":
            playerLevel = 1
            pMaxHP += 10
            playersHP = pMaxHP
            pMaxMP += 0
            playersMP = pMaxMP
            trollsHP += 0
            mobLevel += 0
            trolls += 0
            playersGold += 30
            dmgBonus += 0
            classDMGbonus += 3
            weaponBreak += 0
            trollBonus += 0
            healthPot += 2
            manaPot += 0
```

I know I probably have a lot of code that could be cleaned up, but I'm still learning and I'm using this program more to see what I can and can't do, and I think it is fun.

Thank you for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

The error message

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

isn't complaining that it thinks you want to convert `healthPot` to a string.

`healthPot` is *already* a string, and Python is complaining that you're trying to concatenate an integer to it ... which would have to implicitly convert the integer to a string in order to do so.

I don't know how `healthPot` ended up as a string, but this is definitely the case, as adding the line

```
print(type(healthPot))
```

immediately before the `healthPot += 1` line will confirm.